# Como fazer leitura de PDF

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf

Eu estou criando um script para pegar um pdf e reescreve-ló em texto.

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from slate import PDF
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call
import uuid

#pego pdf existente
url = "/tmp/arquivo.pdf"
    with open(url, "r") as arq:
        out = arq.read()

    #novo arquivo para parsear o pdf
    newfile = "/tmp/teste/" + str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".txt"

    with open(newfile, "wb") as arq:
       arq.write(out)
```

Porém a saída é esta:

> 'PDF-1.7\r\n%\xa1\xb3\xc5\xd7\r\n1 0 obj\r\n<>>>\r\nendobj\r\n2 0 obj\r\n<

O resultado não foi o esperado e uma pessoa me passou sobre o call (mas não me explicou) e sobre PDFbox do Java, daí ele me passou esse código:

```
call(["java", "-jar", "/tmp/teste/pdfbox-app-2.0.3.jar", "ExtractText", out, newfile])
```

Tentei usar mas não consegui, já começa dando erro pelo "java". Fiz teste chamando "python" e funciona mas não é isso que eu preciso.

Pesquisei mas não encontrei fazendo uma chamada pra Java como exemplo. Será que rola usar?

Eu quero um texto legível e que o pdf seja impresso na ordem certa (respeitando colunas, linhas, etc..)
Como que faço para converter um pdf em um texto?

Answer (score 4):

Ler um PDF é um processo bem mais complicado do que parece. 
Se você quer só extrair o texto, essa biblioteca `slate` que você está importando é o que faz isso - só que na sua tentativa você sequer chama o slate.

Outra coisa é que um arquivo PDF deve ser aberto para leitura no modo binário -  você coloca "rb" no modo do open - senão, por padrão, ele abre como texto, e a tradução automática destrói a estrutura dos dados lidos.

```
from slate import PDF
from tempfile import mktemp
...

output_name = mktemp() + ".txt"

with open(url, 'rb') as pdf_file, open(output_name, 'wt') as output:
    doc = PDF(pdf_file)
    for page in doc:
        output.write(page + '\n')
```

(O exemplo de como usar o slate está em: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slate)

Comment: Ui, consegui usar a tal biblioteca do Java.
Pena que ainda saiu bugado com a primeira página praticamente inteira assim: "!"#$ % &".
Mas enfim... 
Vou tentar o Slate!